# dnsmasq, address of host with no TLD with address=

Tags: domain-name-system, dnsmasq

We want `dnsmasq` to resolve a name for a local host. When using the `address=/host/address` syntax, if host has no TLD (as shown), it does not resolve. It turns it into a FQDN, which causes it to return the name of the local Microsoft domain controller.

For example, if we have this:

```
address=/domain.com/192.168.1.45
address=/server1/192.168.1.100
address=/server2/192.168.1.200
```

A ping for `server1` or `server2` will return `192.168.1.45`, with the FQDN showing `server1.domain.com` (even though we don't specify that in the ping).

I've check the docs, this and other sites, but I can't even find anyone that's having this same issue, much less a resolution.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't `dnsmasq` doing it, it's your host's DNS settings appending a TLD or search domain. Remove the `search` or `domain` portions from `/etc/resolv.conf`, but be aware that it's probably not the right way to solve your issues.

The better way to solve this is always query with a trailing dot. So you'd just have to remember to always use `server1.` to query with, not `server1`.